# 3D Asset Creation. "Joining" parts VS Hidden/Redundant Faces?

Tags: 3d, 3d-meshes, maya

I am trying to create a Laser Cannon in 3D art program Maya. It is for use in a game made in Unreal Engine.

I have this same 'problem' with many aspects of my 3D CG Art but this is just one simple example of the problem.

I'm unsure whether it is better to chop all faces out and link the meshes together, or indeed just have the two (or more) objects intersect each-other (which seems to be a much simpler way to create the art (including doing the UV mapping, texturing, etc).

[image]

[image]

The cannon looks fine to me as it is, but I wonder if this will cause problems using this approach going forward. Many tutorials I watch they go to much trouble to chop out all of the faces and join the barrel to the mounting dome.

Should I stop doing this and start joining them?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, combine the meshes. Such that what we expect to be a single object arrives as a single thing in the engine. There is no technical limitation preventing an object from having disconnected triangles. So when I say "combine meshes" I don't mean removing internal faces and linking surfaces.

---

Do you need to render this model with depth test disabled?

*For example, you might want to render a weapon in a first person shooter with depth test disabled  as a solution for the weapon clipping through objects in the world (there are other solutions to that problem.*

If you answered yes. Then you don't want any internal faces. So cut and remove them.

---

Do you need to render this model with transparency?

*For example, perhaps you want to have it fade in and fade out.*

If you answered yes. Then you don't want any internal faces, they would be visible with transparency. So cut and remove them.

---

Will cutting the faces result in more faces than you had before?

*For example, you can model a wall with two triangles. Let us say there is a stair on the wall, covering a large area of it. If you want to cut the wall to only the visible part, you will be making the wall with a series of small triangles, when the wall only required two before.*

If you answered yes. That is an argument for not cutting them, because it means you are increasing the polygon count.

Common wisdom is to eliminate any internal faces to increase performance. However, any modern engine will support a depth pre-pass so hidden faces aren't a performance problem. On the other hand, more triangles might result in worse performance.

---

As per joining them, you should consider if the model will be rigged and animated, and how. Having separate pieces might give you the desired result (i.e. it is a mechanical piece, or you are going for that artistic style), otherwise you probably want to join them.

---

Now, imagine you went with one option but turns out actually you need the other option. Which of the two options when turning out to be wrong, results in less total effort counting the effort to fix it?

Let us say the version that is made of multiple pieces takes `x` amount of effort to make.

Then the version that have the parts cut - and possibly joint - takes that same effort `x` plus some extra effort `y` for cutting and joining, for a total of `x + y`.

Now, if you initially did the the version with multiple pieces and it turns out you need the other, you do that same `x + y` effort, except you didn't do it in one go.

But if you initially did the other one, and you need to cut it into multiple pieces - and possibly fill the holes - you are going to need the same `x + y` effort plus some `z` effort for splitting and patching, for a total of `x + y + z`. That is worst. *This is also an argument for keeping a version of the model before going into cutting and joining, just in case.*

So, you can start making the version with multiple pieces, and only do the cutting and joining if you have a reason to. *Be it performance, or animation, or some rendering tricks, or whatever.*

---

And finally that brings me to this: If you can try the models in engine, do so. You want to find out any unforeseen problems that may arise from importing to the engine.

If you don't know how or where the model will be used, on one hand you have possibly it looking wrong sometimes (e.g. without depth test, or with transparency), and on the other you have possibly worse performance (i.e. polygon count). So it makes sense to err on the side of correctness.

But if you do know. So you can get feedback and improve your process it to better fit the use case. Now, is this for a client? If it is, perhaps you can ask the client. If it isn't… Did you or your team make proof of concept without custom models? *It makes sense to test mechanics with simple geometric shapes or generic models before making custom art.* So, try the models there, or get somebody to do it.